# Touch area on the HTML5 canvas using native javascript code

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a one canvas with fixed width and height, in that canvas I have drawn background image using drawImage() method. In the background image there are some objects like  ants(static) when the user touches the ants then that particular area should clear(or ant image should disappear) or should through one alert box like you have found ant. I have searched for finding the particular touch area but I got only finding x and y co-ordinates by using touchstart event. I don't want to compare with x and y co-ordinates with ant position in image. I know the ants positions on image. 
this code I got while searching

```
   $('#id').on('touchstart', function(){
   alert("Touched");    
});
```

But I am not drawing images through html img tag. 
Any help would appreciated lot.
In the touchstart event there are some radiousX and radiousY properties to find area but I did't get aany examples on those properties.

Here is one problem: Anybody through a solution for this problem???
For example there is one city image, in that I need to touch some buildings after touching a particular building, can we get alert box like you find your home???

Comment: Why don't you want to compare the touch coordinates with the ants coordinates?

Comment: @Butt4cak3 If i compare with x and y co-ordinates it takes more touches to compare exact numbers so instead of comparing x and y co-ordinates we can get touch area(space of finger touches) for comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the x and y coordinates of the touch with the coordinates of the ant is the right way to go. Yes, it's very hard to touch an exact spot, but you don't have to. You can check whether the touch coordinates are in a specific range, let's say at most 10 pixels away from the ant coordinate.

```
// touchX and touchY are the touch coordinates
// antX and antY are the ant's coordinates

// Is touchX between (antX - 10) and (antX + 10)?
if (touchX >= antX - 10 && touchX <= antX + 10) {

    // Is touchY between (antY - 10) and (antY + 10)?
    if (touchY >= antY - 10 && touchY <= antY + 10) {
        // The user touched the ant
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It works great. Thanks, One small question, If I don't know the ants co-ordinates then how do we find the weather that particular area touches or not??

Comment: You need to know the coordinates. Otherwise you can't detect it.

Comment: For example there is one city image, in that I need to touch some buildings after touching a particular building, can we get alert box like you find your home???

Comment: Is it? We can find but thing is that whole background image contains buildings we don't draw separate separate building images on one single image. If possible please provide me one example/code.

Comment: You could need something like an imagemap for that, or at least you'd need to know the coordinates of your buildings. If it's all just one image file then that's not enough information for the program to be able to figure out what you want - you need to define the buildings location somehow.

Comment: @BrianDHall Thanks for gud info. K if I find out the co-ordinates of all buildings then I can figure out where is my home. Suppose background image(City images) having the zooming option or scrolling option then co-ordinates will get change then how could we match them with our buildings co-ordinates?? Eagerly waiting for your great response

Comment: In short: trial and error. Zoom is kind of a filthy mess. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers - it's doable, but it isn't trivial for most cases. If your image is a fixed, known size then you can just use script to get the full coordinates of your image and make your own calculations from there - if it's an 800x600 image but the browser reports it smaller/large, then you know something is amiss.

Comment: @BrianDHall SIr, I am developing game for mobile devices not for browers. I am facing problems for screen size compatibility(Width and Height). Zooming also changing in mobile to mobile

Comment: @Mallikarjun This is, as far as I'm aware, just an inherently tricky aspect of mobile devices and pixel-location sensitive coding. It will really depend on lots of complicated factors, and this is getting out of my area of expertise. If you have an issue I'd strongly encourage you to work up a simplified example fiddle with stripped down/isolated code and post a new question. It's far too difficult to even begin to address in a comment or as a general statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my small project multi touch canvas2d js.

You can track all 10 fingers on mobile screen.

I made also detect rect area.
[Source code](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/multi-touch-canvas-handler)

```js
 
function MOBILE_CONTROL () {
 
  this.X =  null;
  this.Y =  null;
  this.LAST_X_POSITION = null;
  this.LAST_Y_POSITION = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH = 'NO';
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 = null;  
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 = null;  
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X8 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = 1;
  this.SCREEN = [window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight]; 
  this.SCREEN.W = this.SCREEN[0];
  this.SCREEN.H = this.SCREEN[1];
  //Application general
  this.AUTOR = "Nikola Lukic";
  this.APPLICATION_NAME = "TestApplication";
  this.SET_APPLICATION_NAME = function (value) {
            if (typeof value != 'string')
                throw 'APPLICATION_NAME must be a string!';
            if (value.length < 2 || value.length > 20)
                throw 'APPLICATION_NAME must be 2-20 characters long!';
            this.APPLICATION_NAME = value;
        };
  this.APP = function(){/*construct*/};
  this.APP.BODY = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  this.APP.BODY.SET_STYLE = function (string) {this.style = string;}
  this.APP.BODY.SET_BACKGROUND_COLOR = function (color) {this.style.backgroundColor = color;}
  this.APP.BODY.SET_COLOR = function (color) {this.style.Color = color;} 
  this.APP.BODY.ADD_DIV = function (id , style , innerHTML) { 
  var n = document.createElement('div');
  var divIdName = id;
  n.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
  n.setAttribute('style',style);
  n.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  this.appendChild(n);
  };
  this.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS = function (id,width_,height_) { 
  var n = document.createElement('canvas');
  var divIdName = id;
  n.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
  n.setAttribute('width',width_);
  n.setAttribute('height',height_);
  //n.innerHTML = 'Element is here';
  this.appendChild(n);
  };
  console.log('<MOBILE_CONTROL JavaScript class>');
  console.log('status:MOBILE_CONTROL FINISH LOADING');
  console.log('EASY_IMPLEMENTATION!');
  
}
function CANVAS_DRAW(){
var run = true;
var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('touchstart', MDPORT, false); 
function MDPORT(){
if (run) {
clearInterval(timer);
run = false;
}
else {
timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
run = true;
}
}
var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
var UPDOWN = 1,CONTROL_WIDTH = 0;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
setInterval(randomColor, 5000);
timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
function randomColor() {
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
function makeHarmonograph() {
f1 = (f1  / 10) % 10;
f2 = (f2 / 40) % 10;
f3 = (f3 + Math.random() / 80) % 10;
f4 = (f4 + Math.random() / 411) % 10;
p1 += 0.5 % (Math.PI*2)
drawHarmonograph();
}
function drawHarmonograph() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 850, 450);
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1100, 400);
 
ctx.translate(511, 0);
ctx.rotate(1.57);
///////////
 // Draw guides
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';
 ctx.lineWidth = A1 ;
 
 ctx.translate(111, 1);
 ctx.rotate(0.01);
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN+1;}
 if (UPDOWN>51){CONTROL_WIDTH=1; } 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN-0.1;}
 if (UPDOWN<1){CONTROL_WIDTH=0; } 
 
 // Set line styles
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#099909';
 ctx.lineWidth = UPDOWN;
 
 // check input
 ctx.miterLimit = UPDOWN;
 
 // Draw lines
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(111,100);
 for (i=0;i<121;i++){
 var dy = i%2==0 ? 25 : -25 ;
 ctx.lineTo(Math.pow(i,1.5)*2,75+dy);
 }
 ctx.stroke();
 return false;
 
ctx.translate(444, 333);
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Overlapping harmonics with JavaScript, wait secund.",5,25);
 
ctx.stroke();
 
}
}
function CANVAS_DRAW_1(){
var run = true;
var timer = null;
 
timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
run = true;
 
var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
var UPDOWN = 1,CONTROL_WIDTH = 0;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_1").getContext("2d");
setInterval(randomColor, 5000);
timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
function randomColor() {
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
function makeHarmonograph() {
f1 = (f1  / 10) % 10;
f2 = (f2 / 40) % 10;
f3 = (f3 + Math.random() / 80) % 10;
f4 = (f4 + Math.random() / 411) % 10;
p1 += 0.5 % (Math.PI*2)
drawHarmonograph();
}
function drawHarmonograph() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 850, 450);
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
ctx.translate(0, 250);
ctx.beginPath();
if (A1 > 100) {}
for (var t = 0; t < 100; t+=0.1) {
var x = A1 * Math.sin(f1 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d1 * t) + A2 * Math.sin(f2 * t + Math.PI * p2) * Math.exp(-d2 * t);
var y = A3 * Math.sin(f3 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d3 * t) + A4 * Math.sin(f4 * t + Math.PI * p4) * Math.exp(-d4 * t);
//ctx.lineTo(x*x, y/x);
ctx.lineTo(x*x+1, y+1/x);
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.translate(A1, 0);
ctx.rotate(1.57);
ctx.beginPath();
for (var t = 0; t < 100; t+=0.1) {
var x = A1 * A3* Math.sin(f1 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d1 * t) + A2 * Math.sin(f2 * t + Math.PI * p2) * Math.exp(-d2 * t);
var y = A3 * Math.sin(f3 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d3 * t) + A4 * Math.sin(f4 * t + Math.PI * p4) * Math.exp(-d4 * t);
ctx.lineTo(x*x+1, y+1/x);
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
///////////
 
 
 
 // Draw guides
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';
 ctx.lineWidth = A1 ;
 
 
 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN+1;}
 if (UPDOWN>51){CONTROL_WIDTH=1; } 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN-0.1;}
 if (UPDOWN<1){CONTROL_WIDTH=0; } 
 
 // Set line styles
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#099909';
 ctx.lineWidth = UPDOWN;
 
 // check input
 ctx.miterLimit = 5;
 
 // Draw lines
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,100);
 for (i=0;i<124;i++){
 var dy = i%2==0 ? 25 : -25 ;
 ctx.lineTo(Math.pow(i,1.5)*2,75+dy);
 }
 ctx.stroke();
 return false;
 
ctx.translate(A1, 210);
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Overlapping harmonics with JavaScript, wait secund.",5,25);
}
}
function CANVAS_DRAW_2(){
 
var timer = null;
  
 
var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
 
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_2").getContext("2d");
setInterval(randomColor, 5000);
timer = setInterval(t, 1);
function randomColor() {
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
function t() {
 
r1();
}
function r1() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CONTROL.SCREEN.W, CONTROL.SCREEN.H);
ctx.save();
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, CONTROL.SCREEN.W, CONTROL.SCREEN.H);
 
ctx.beginPath();
 
 
var x = CONTROL.X;
var y = CONTROL.Y;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
 
ctx.fillRect(x, y-400, 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(x-400, y, 2500, 1);
ctx.fillText(" ( targetX:" + CONTROL.X + " ( targetY: "+ CONTROL.Y + " ) ",x,y);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.font="10px Arial";
ctx.fillText(" JavaScript ",x- CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3.4);
ctx.fillText(" welcome here , canvas example with MOBILE_TOUCH() ",x -  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3.2);
ctx.fillText(" no css files need, pure js ",x -  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3);
if (CONTROL.X > CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2 && CONTROL.X < CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2 + 300 && CONTROL.Y > CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2 && CONTROL.Y < CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2 + 100) {
ctx.strokeStyle = "lime";
}
else{
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
}
ctx.strokeRect( CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2, CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2, 300, 100);
ctx.fillText(" HUB DETECT ",  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2, CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2);
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_51 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 , 2500, 1);
}
 
 // Draw lines
  
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("MOBILE_TOUCH example ",5,25);
 
}
}
//definition
var CONTROL = new MOBILE_CONTROL();
//CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas");
//CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas_1");
CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas_2",CONTROL.SCREEN.W,CONTROL.SCREEN.H);
CONTROL.APP.BODY.SET_STYLE('margin-left:-10px;padding:0;border:none;');
//CANVAS_DRAW();
//CANVAS_DRAW_1();
CANVAS_DRAW_2();
 
//<!-- SCREEN.prototype.sayHello = function(){alert ('hello' + "sss" );}; -->
//###################################################################
//EVENTS
//###################################################################  
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) 
{ 
 
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'NO') {
 var touch = event.touches[0];
 CONTROL.X = touch.pageX;
 CONTROL.Y = touch.pageY;
 console.log('TOUCH START AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
 
}
else if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'YES') {
  var touches_changed = event.changedTouches;
   
   for (var i=0; i<touches_changed.length;i++) {
   
   //CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1
  console.log("multi touch : x" + CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + ":(" +touches_changed[i].pageX + ")");
  switch(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX)
{
case 1:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 2:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 3:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 4:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 5:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 6:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 7:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 8:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 9:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 10:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
default:
  //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + 1;
  
  
  }
}
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH = 'YES';
 
},false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) 
{ 
var touch = event.touches[0];
CONTROL.X = touch.pageX;
CONTROL.Y = touch.pageY;
console.log('TOUCH MOVE AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
//#############
 if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'YES') {
  var touches_changed = event.changedTouches;
   
   for (var i=0; i<touches_changed.length;i++) {
   
   //CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1
  console.log("multi touch : x" + CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + ":(" +touches_changed[i].pageX + ")");
  switch(i)
{
case 1:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 2:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 3:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 4:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 5:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 6:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 7:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 8:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 9:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 10:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
default:
  //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
}}
//#############
event.preventDefault();
},false);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
document.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) 
{ 
CONTROL.LAST_X_POSITION = CONTROL.X;  
CONTROL.LAST_Y_POSITION = CONTROL.Y; 
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH = 'NO';
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = 1;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 = null;
console.log('LAST TOUCH POSITION AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
},false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(event) 
{ 
console.log('BREAK - LAST TOUCH POSITION AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '(,(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
}, false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```